# How to line-number 1,5,10,15,20,25... in Program Listing in Lyx

Tags: listings, lyx

I basically want every 5th line numbered, but would like to keep to 5,10,15,20,... as that seems intuitive to readers. So that means 1,5,10,15,... The first gap is 4, all subsequent ones are 5. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: How come this has an accepted answer when the question is clearly LyX oriented? None of the answers below, so far, has any hint for LyX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a combination of `firstnumber` and `numberfirstline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left,stepnumber=5,firstnumber=1,numberfirstline}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
a
b
c
d
A
B
C
D
E
a
b
c
d
e
Q
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image: listings]

[I assume you are using the `listings` package.]

Answer (score 2):

When you use the key,  `stepnumber=5`, the numbers are incremented in steps of 5. However, under that scenario, your numbers will come out to be 5, 10... Not the sequence you asked for. So, you will have to coax LaTeX to start your number from the very first line. You add `numberfirstline,firstnumber=1` and for that purpose.

From the relevant documentation,

> `numberfirstline= true|false` Default: false
>
> The first line of each listing gets numbered (if numbers are on at
>   all) even if the line number is not divisible by stepnumber.
>
> `firstnumber= auto|last| number` Default: auto
>
> `auto` lets the package choose the
>   first number: a new listing starts with number one, a named listing
>   continues the most recent same-named listing (see below), and a stand
>   alone file begins with the number corresponding to the first input
>   line. last continues the numbering of the most recent listing and
>   number sets it to the number.

Anyway, here is your MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=C,numberfirstline,firstnumber=1,numbers=left, stepnumber=5}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a;
  printf("Enter an integer\n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("Integer that you have entered is %d\n", a);
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output,

[image]

---

I am not sure which language you are using, perhaps you would like to use,
`basicstyle=\ttfamily` as well to make output more program like. (If you are not already using that.)